# How these per processor run queues get populated ?

Tags: linux, kernel

LIke, Ok now the OS is booted up and i have just one shell running on my quad core system. Now what happens when i go on adding new processes. where do they go ? When do they go ? Inside fork() implementation do they handle this ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is about. Do you want to know how a OS manages multiple processes and threads? There different ways of doing this. osdev is a good place for learning the basic ideas (take this article for example http://wiki.osdev.org/Scheduling_Algorithms ).